# Workflow not forwarding after user task in jbpm5

Tags: java, mysql, drools, jbpm

I have a user task in a workflow.
Im able to process the human task but the flow is not forwarding further.
Without any exception the flow stops there, other tasks following the user task is not getting executed.

Kindly help me in this regard.
1. Could there be any configuration changes needed for jbpm5.0.
2. Is there anything else that im missing.

```
      KnowledgeBase kbase = readKnowledgeBase("taskprocess.rf");
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = createKnowledgeSession(kbase);

        /*Create the knowledge base for HelloProcss.bpmn */

        KnowledgeRuntimeLogger logger = KnowledgeRuntimeLoggerFactory.newThreadedFileLogger(ksession, "testlog", 1000);
        CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler taskHandler = new CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler(ksession);
        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", taskHandler);
        //JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger logger = new JPAWorkingMemoryDbLogger(ksession);
        //taskHandler.connect();

        System.out.println(" started the humantask");
        ksession.startProcess("persistask");    
        ksession.fireAllRules();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add the user name administrator in the "TaskServiceSession"

```
         taskSession.addUser(new User("administrator"));
```

With this the workflow progresses and completes the remaining tasks after the user task is completed.
You must have the administrator role in order to run any process. It is a requirement

Comment: Is this required  even when the admininstrator user is already present in db?

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the thread that register the human task handler died (ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", taskHandler);)
You need to have a global session with the Human Task handler attached listening the Human Task component for notification about Task Completions.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks krish and salaboy.I understood the problem but still clueless in finding out how to create a global ksession with human task handler listening for notifications. Would be much helpful if i get some examples.

Comment: We need to add the user name administrator in the "TaskServiceSession"

            
`taskSession.addUser(new User("administrator"));`

With this the workflow progresses and completes the remaining tasks after the user task is completed.
But i doubt whether its a bug or a logic of must having an administrator.

Comment: You must have the administrator role in order to run any process. It is a requirement.

Comment: Great.
But please clarify that in the documentation so that others will not spend much time in figuring out the problem as i did.Thanks

Comment: jBPM5 is a community project, you can help us to improve the docs. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify how you are completing the task, are you using the Eclipse or web-based client for example?  And what happens in your main class after starting the process, does it just terminate?  In that case, Salaboy is probably right, as the thread that created the task and executing the process probably already died before you completed the task, so it will not continue execution.

Adding a long Thread.sleep in your main class would probably allow you to continue execution for testing.

Comment: My workflow:  start-->user task-->script task--> end.
Im using eclipse to run it and once the user completes the human task the flow terminates there. i didnt get any exception and the further tasks are not executing.